Swift (UI) for MacOS: DatePicker Auto-Focus Time Text
Context
I have a MacOS app built with Swift (UI). It has a menu bar icon, with a window that pops out upon clicking the icon.
Requirement
I'd like to auto-focus onto the DatePicker()'s text when the window pops out (upon clicking the menu bar icon). Currently, this actually happens automatically, but only for the first time. Afterwards, there's no auto-focusing (see difference in DatePicker()s in the screenshots below):


Relevant Code
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // irrelevant elements
            HStack{
                // irrelevant elements
                
                DatePicker("Schedule Notifications", selection: $notificationTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .datePickerStyle(.stepperField)
            }
        }
        // irrelevant modifiers
    }


Try this approach using @FocusState ... and the modifier .focused(...).
For example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var notificationTime = Date()
    @FocusState private var isDatePickerFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 77){
            DatePicker("Schedule Notifications", selection: $notificationTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .datePickerStyle(.stepperField)
                .focused($isDatePickerFocused)
            
            Button("Focus on DatePicker") {
                isDatePickerFocused = true
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
          //  isDatePickerFocused = true  // <--- if required
        }
    }
}


Hey, thanks for posting this; the solution is definitely a step in the right direction, as it makes the date picker focused past just its first open.
However, upon clicking off, onto another app (e.g. XCode), then tapping the app's menu bar icon again, the datepicker doesn't auto-focus.

I've investigated into the .defaultFocus() property by wrapping it in a Form{}, but it seems to run into the same pitfall as this solution.
